# how to obtain a DOM like representation of the structure of a Java method in a compiled class?

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode

I need to gather certain information from a method in a (compiled) Java class.
Among other things, I would like to find out all the existing method calls and who is the receiver of each method invocation.

Is there a library for obtaining a convenient representation of a compiled class and its declared methods (something like a DOM view) that can abstract me from interpreting the byte code my self?

Comment: I know at leas two frameworks: ASM and BCEL. Read comparison at [Jakarta’s BCEL vs. ObjectWeb’s ASM Frameworks](http://chaoticjava.com/posts/jakartas-bcel-vs-objectwebs-asm/)

Comment: With [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) you can use [visitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to iterate over the methods of a class along with their code, as well as the [bytecode instructions](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/Visitor.html) of that code, including [invoke](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/Visitor.html#visitInvokeInstruction%28org.apache.bcel.generic.InvokeInstruction%29) instructions. I'd make this an answer but the question has been closed.